# How to sort DynamoDB query result without specifying range key value

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am building a DynamoDB table and am running into issues on how to best structure my indexes. I have 3 queries I need to perform.

My Table:

```
AttributeDefinitions:
  # This is large groups that can have many events
  - AttributeName: groupId
    AttributeType: S
  # An event can have many actions
  - AttributeName: eventId
    AttributeType: S
  # Each item has a unique actionId
  - AttributeName: actionId
    AttributeType: S
  # Each item has a creation date
  - AttributeName: createdAt
    AttributeType: S
  # Some type I need to filter by (enum: trigger|task for example)
  - AttributeName: actionType
    AttributeType: S

# Main query to return items by action ID - that works fine
KeySchema:
  - AttributeName: groupId
    KeyType: HASH
  - AttributeName: actionId
    KeyType: RANGE
```

These are the 3 queries I need to achieve:

1. Fetch a single item

Right now I do a getItem with

```
Key: {
  groupId,
  actionId
}
```

Works great.

2. Fetch all items (actions) by eventId

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM theTable WHERE eventId = 123
```

If I do this local index then that works great:

```
KeySchema:
  - AttributeName: groupId
    KeyType: HASH
  - AttributeName: eventId
    KeyType: RANGE
```

3. Fetch all items with the actionType='trigger' ordered by createdAt date that belong to a groupId (irrespective of eventId)

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM theTable WHERE actionType = 'trigger' AND groupId = 123 SORT BY createdAt
```

This is the one giving me issues. I would like to query my data and have it returned sorted by date. However I need to query using another field as my RANGE.  So I if I add createdAt as my range I can't use actionType to filter. If I use actionType then there is no sort.

How can I best structure this table? In terms of amnount of data. There can be many groups (groupId). Each group can have many events (eventId). But each event is likely to only have <100 actions (actionId).

Comment: What is the exact key condition expression you are using right now?

Comment: @MatthewPope your question helped me see my issue more clearly - I can in fact query without the createdAt value but not with my desired filter. I've edited the question.

Comment: So are you asking about how to specify a sort in a DynamoDB query, or are you asking how to design your table to enable the queries you want? If it’s the latter, it might be helpful for you to list out your queries as English sentences or as SQL.

Comment: I've added an sql to illustrate. Whether I need help with the query or the structure of my index I guess depends on what is needed to happen. Hopefully the sql clarifies?

Comment: Is that the only query you need to do? If there are others, can you list them as well? With DynamoDB, you get great performance, but the trade off is that you need to design your tables with all of your access patterns in mind.

Comment: Since you asked... My schema is more complex - ive edited the question with the entire schema and the three queries I use. Only #3 is giving me issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to implement a query like
`SELECT * FROM theTable WHERE actionType = 'trigger' AND groupId = 123 SORT BY createdAt` in DynamoDB, you need to have an index with a hash key of `groupId` and a composite sort key of `actionTypeCreatedAt` (which is, predictably, the actionType, a delimiter, and then the createdAt date).

In your index, the data would look like this (assuming a delimiter of "_" in the sort key):

```
groupId | actionTypeCreatedAt
--------|------------------------------
    123 | trigger_2019-06-30T08:30:00Z
    123 | trigger_2019-07-05T23:00:00Z
    123 | trigger_2019-07-20T10:15:00Z
    123 | action2_2019-06-25T15:10:00Z
    123 | action2_2019-07-08T02:45:00Z
```

Now, to achieve the query you desire, you would need to use a key condition expression of `groupId = 123 AND begins_with(actionTypeCreatedAt, "trigger_")`. DynamoDB will automatically sort the results by the sort key, and since all of the query results have the same `actionType` prefix, the results will be sorted only by the `createdAt` date.

Comment: Ahhh.. So when I put an Item will then create the actionType, createdAt and actionTypeCreatedAt field manually correct?

Comment: Yes, you have to populate that field in your application before sending the item to DynamoDB.